# How to read brightness and contrast of a video?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Does anyone know how to read brightness and contrast of a video using open cv with c++? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS)` & `VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST)` if I find out your question properly.

Comment: Thanks aloneStrider for you answer, but when I ran the code, it just returned 0.Biscally, what I did it just like that :1- VideoCapture cap(0); 2- double Brightness= cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS); 3- cout<<"the brightness is "<<Brightness<<endl;

Comment: cap is a VideoCapture but initialized null so brightness is 0 obviously.

Comment: So, what is your suggestion then?

Comment: You must initialize cap first with your video then you can read brightness property of that from its images.